# Subtract specific values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract objects from a dataframe via the `.iloc` function and convert those to `int` to perform some operations on them. Specifically, I want to subtract two values `V3 = V1 - V2`.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

V1 = df.iloc[[0],[0]]
V2 = df.iloc[[1],[1]]
```

I've tried some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas) that convert the whole column but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you looking for `df.col1 - df.col2`?

Comment: `df['col3'] = df['col1'] - df['col2']` ... is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey, no I can't subtract the whole column unfortunately. It has to be only those two specific values.  ...

Comment: So, just `v3 = df.iloc[0, 0] - df.iloc[1, 1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
v3 = df.iloc[0, 0] - df.iloc[1, 1]
```

which will return `-3`.